# Using minoccurs="0" and nillable ="false" in XSD for an element type string is valid?

Tags: xml, xsd

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Name" nillable="false">
        <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:maxLength value="25"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

For above element when request element has null value, will it fail in validation?

I got no error for below xml request-

```
 <con:name></con:name> - no error.
```

Please let me know if the type is string and minoccurs is zero and nillable is false what will be response on xml validation.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'd say, it is in a comment, so `minOccurs` is valid, and it isn't empty (because not existent).

Comment: Here my requirement is like name should not be null when name tag present in request xml.Above xsd will support ?

Comment: But your name tag is not present in the XML. It is in a comment.

Comment: sry it is not in a comment... I added wrongly.  <con:name></con:name>

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason with this declaration why an empty element should fail validation.

`minOccurs="0"` means the element can be omitted: it has no effect on how the element is validated if it is present.

`nillable="false"` means you can't have the attribute `xsi:nil="true"`. But you don't have this attribute so this won't make it invalid. You don't need to make it `nillable`, since the element's type allows empty content anyway, there is no need to label it as `nil` (unless perhaps you want to distinguish a value of `""` from a value of `"unknown"`.

Answer (score 1):

Validation will not fail in my opinion for that xml fragment.
First, minOccurs refers to minimum number of elements in a sequence so it applies to the parent element of con:name (if any) but not the element itself.

> Occurrence indicators are used to define how often an element can occur.

'nillable' refers to the nil attribute: nil="true" used to assign the null value to an element.

More details at http://www.dimuthu.org/blog/2008/08/18/xml-schema-nillabletrue-vs-minoccurs0/comment-page-1/

Answer (score 1):

## `nillable`

It works on the data inside the element restricting it's value, `nillable="false"` that means that you **can’t set an element value as `null`**. An  element where `nillable="true"` **can have `null` value inside it** at that it will have an attribute **`xsi:nil="true"`** marking it as `null`.

## `minOccurs`

It is the rule/restriction over element telling how many times the element can be repeated in the following xml, a `minOccurs="0"` tells that the element is not mandatory in the `xml` and with it or without it is a valid `xml` as per the schema.

A value `minOccurs="1"` on the other hand tells that the element must be present in the `Xml` at least once else the `XSD Validation` will fail.

---

Now for the answer **No**, it will not fail the validation unless you add `<xs:minLength value="1" />` to it since the datatatype is `xs:string` what you are considering as `null` is `empty` string by putting `<xs:minLength value="1" />` you are telling the string must have 1 character and not be empty.

```xml
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Name" nillable="false">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="25"/>
        <xs:minLength value="1" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

As this is not `null` but empty that why we check a string to be `null` or Empty in `c#` with `String.IsNullOrEmpty(String)` and the difference between them can be un understand as below.
[image]

Comment: are you sure that an element where nillable="true" can have null value inside it? may be it can have empty value, and not null?

Comment: @AndreyM.Stepanov An empty string is nil in some other language, but in XML Schema as a language for something to be nil, it must have the xsi:nil attribute set to “true”. So in the question above even with `<Name/>` the schema will still not fail (as it's not considered as null) but if you remove the `<Name>` element the schema validation will fail. Ref https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_nil